# python validate Oracle username/passwords without using cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle

I need to validate that user provided data for oracle account information is correct.  I tried to use cx_Oracle but the version of OCI.DLL that is on my servers (which I can't upgrade) seems to not be the correct version for cx_Oracle.

How can I validate username/passwords without using cx_Oracle?

Comment: Well, if you can't connect to the database, you'll need some alternative data source which can tell you what the valid user names and passwords are. Hopefully, there will be none, or else I'd be worrying about your database security.

Comment: The script will be run on the local machine, so I am not to worried about db security.  What I have is a series of other scripts that do various things.  I have written a central GUI that i can give the non-db expert users an easy way to use the other tools.  The problem is that the other tools require the DB username/password to work.  So what I want to do is take the user provided credentials and then validate that they are correct before I launch the desired tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't compile cx_Oracle, you have two options:

- use ODBC (for example [PyODBC](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/));
- use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) to interact with `sqlplus`.

Comment: Can you provide a link to an example where pyodbc connects to Oracle?  Im getting the error pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The driver doesn't support the version of ODBC behavior that the application request.

Comment: So far if I use cnxn = pyodbc.connect(DRIVER='{Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}', uid='uname', pwd='pword')  this will work.  But when I try to add the option database='iname' it gives the Invalid connectio nstring attribute

Comment: I was able to get this working.  Since I wanted to create a variable for both the instance and the server I created a string:  connectString='DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}:Server=' + strServername + ':1521/' + strInstance + ';uid=' + strUsername + ';pwd=' + strPassword.  Then I passed that as cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connectString).  I wrapped that with a Try/Except to catch the errors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely the version of your cx_Oracle module.

You have to be extremely careful when you install the module, to choose the appropriate version for your oracle installation.

http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/

If you can't connect to the database using cx_Oracle, you might have a hard time checking the accuracy of the information

If you have sql*plus installed, you might try to start a process using the *subprocess* module and check if you can connect, but in my opinion, you might be better of with fixing cx_Oracle

**Edit:** Meant the subprocess module.

Here is how can you do it with subprocess:

```
import subprocess

def is_login_valid(user, password, instance):
  output = subprocess.check_output("sqlplus %s/%s@%s" %(user, password, instance))
  return (output.find("ORA-01017") == -1 and output.find("ORA-12154") == -1)
```

Comment: I went through all versions (5.1 and 5.0.4) of cx_Oracle that applied to python 2.7 and Oracle 10G.  None of them would load.  Using dependency walker it flagged OCI.DLL as not having some of the functions needed.  I can't alter the version of Oracle on the server due to policy.  Sqlplus is installed, but I am not familiar with the multiprocess module.  Can you explain more what you had in mind.

Comment: The multiprocess module allows to spawn processes and listen for their output. If you launch an Sqlplus process from python using the multiprocess module, you could check if it can connect to the database. (By checking for connection errors)

Comment: cx_oracle look on ORACLE_HOME environment variable check if it's referencing the right client and reinstall it.

Comment: @fn Yep, did that.  Another twist is that this particular server has 3 different instance of 10G on it at 3 different versions.  This is what I suspect is actually causing the problem with cx_Oracle.

Comment: @ccwhite1 What is the version of the instance you're trying to connect? Do cx_Oracle throw some error/exception? You could try the source distribution and do some manual install or even 'force' the right dll on setup.py

Comment: Using the subprocess example above, how do you define which oracle instance I will be connecting to?  To connect manually I normally have to alter my ORACLE_HOME variable point to the desired instance.  Also if I call the function above with retval = is_login_valid('uname','pword','iname') the process simply hangs.

Comment: To select your ORACLE_HOME, you can use os.putenv("ORACLE_HOME", "path\to\oraclehome\"). For the hanging process, can you run sqlplus user/password@instance in a command window and send the output so it could give me a hint about what makes it hang ?

Comment: Running the command manually works fine.  It authenticates and drops me to the SQL> prompt.

Comment: When the instance doesn't exist in the TNSNAMES file, it looks like it takes a while before the process returns. It returns with error ORA-12154. I will adjust my example. It might be that which makes it look like it hangs.

Comment: With the addition of the 12154 Im still getting into a hang state.

Comment: FYI, I fall into the hang state if I use a valid or invalid password

Comment: That's weird because for me, the exact same function works correctly. It justs takes some time to return when the instance is not found...

Comment: How much time are we talking about?  Im waiting about 1 min.

Comment: Well, for me, it is about 20-25 seconds with an invalid instance and less than one second for an invalid user or password

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the username & password hashes through some alternate means that doesn't require cx_Oracle, and simply need to verify the password hashes, the [Passlib](http://packages.python.org/passlib) python library may be able to help. It supports both [oracle10g](http://packages.python.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.oracle10.html) and [oracle11g](http://packages.python.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.oracle11.html) hash formats.

Comment: I don't actually have access to hashes.  Users enter their username/pwd and I want to validate them before attempting to run commands with them.